# How to draw transparent primitives using Pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, opengl, pyglet

I want the following code to display a **square** of any **transparency**. I tried 255 (opaque), 0 (fully transparent), 128(half) but nothing seems to work.

```
pyglet.graphics.draw(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS,
                     ('v2f', (0,   0,        # point0
                              0,  32,        # point1
                              32, 32,        # point2
                              32,  0)        # point3
                     ),
                     ('c4B', (255, 0, 0, 128, # color for point0
                              0, 255, 0,   1, # color for point1
                              0, 0, 255, 255, # color for point2
                              0, 0,   0,   0) # color for point3
                     )
                    ) # end draw()
```

This works fine, it makes a square with a gradient.
The square is drawn on top of a sprite, I would like to be able to see the sprite trough the square.

[Image of my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5bpY.png)

- Pyglet v1.2.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code above is **good**!

I just had to add the following somewhere in my program:

```
    pyglet.gl.glEnable(pyglet.gl.GL_BLEND)
    pyglet.gl.glBlendFunc(pyglet.gl.GL_SRC_ALPHA, pyglet.gl.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```